# Looking for an implementation of the Unicode Line Breaking Algorithm written in pure Lua or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unicode, lua, line-breaks

I'm looking for an implementation of the Unicode Line Breaking Algorithm in pure Lua (without C++ + binding) or in a similar simple language that can be "translated" into Lua relatively easy. Unfortunately googling didn't produce any good results.

I'm writing a Lua script for another program that has no way of including any libraries, this is why I can't use existing C++ libraries.

Comment: wich environment? you will probably have to measure text and stuff. we can't help you like that

Comment: Custom Lua 5.2. Yeah, I will have to extract relative character widths for a font separately.

Comment: as far as i know, modern text Rendelers might apply slightly different spacing based on adjacent characters, in order to increase readability. so as long you can't measure text or provide necessary detail, i guess there is no way to do this properly

Comment: When writing a text in a terminal you should distinguish between narrow (1 cell) and wide (2 cells) unicode characters.

Comment: It's not a terminal, it's a Windows app. It uses Arial as a default font. I get that it's over-complicated, but I don't really have other options.